# Call external javascript in the default administration page in Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin

How can I call external javascript in my default admin html page in Django.

I know that using `MEDIA` class I can do this in admin.py file.

Here is the my try:

```
  class PlayerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      class Media:
        js = ('/static_files/js/adminsettings.js')
```

But I am not getting data written in the JavaScript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [path relative to `STATIC_URL` (or `MEDIA_URL`)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions), in your example this may work:

```
  class PlayerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      class Media:
        js = ('js/adminsettings.js',)
```

Also, not that the `js` attribute is a tuple in my example (it can be any iterable, a list, set, etc.)

An alternative is [overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates), which can give you more flexibility, and allow you to apply the same javascript to many models easily.